# How to temporarily store DataTable after Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, datatable

I have two GridViews in which I populate Data on PageStart from database. When I refresh the page (on Post Back), I could not see the datatable content. so I thought of Databinding the GridView again on every pageload. In order to bind the Data I need to store the Data somewhere temporarily. Which one is the Best method to store data temporarily?

In my First Grid there are about 10 rows and in the Second GridView I have about 200 rows. and I'm not using Paging

Comment: Did you mean where is the best place to place code to populate the grids?

Comment: yes like sessions, Viewstate ...

Comment: Why do you want to store the data AFTER populating the grid? Is there a reason? That can narrow down your options.

Comment: You can use ASP.NET Caching to store temp data.

Comment: I'm manipulating data in the Gridview through dropdownlist. So I need to store the Data and to store it I need a datasource!

Comment: Is your `DropDownList` inside the grid or outside?

Comment: In the gridView as a Column

Comment: Can you describe more about the interaction of the columns and the dropdown list? I really don't think you need an extra data storage.

Comment: I'm using the Gridview for shopping List There will be a dropdown in which the user will be selecting the quantity and click on add btn. Then the Data-row has to be copied to a Data-table and Display it in the Cart. and the original row has to be disabled. This is the simple senario I'm using

Comment: Do you have a ShoppingCart table on server side database? Or you are trying to build the ShoppingCart on client side?

Comment: only on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fully working sample using `ViewState` but you can change it for other [caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) methods.

[image]

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvProd" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvProd_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvProd_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litNm"></asp:Literal>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlQty"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add To Cart">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbnAdd" Text="Add To Cart" CommandName="AddToCart"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <hr />
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvCart" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvCart_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvCart_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litNm"></asp:Literal>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQty"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update Qty" CommandName="UpdateCart" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class Product
        {
            public int PID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public Product(int i) { this.PID = i; this.Name = "product " + i.ToString(); }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class CartItem
        {
            public Product Prod { get; set; }
            public int Qty { get; set; }

            public CartItem(Product p, int q) { this.Prod = p; this.Qty = q; }
        }

        public List<CartItem> myCart = new List<CartItem>();
        public List<CartItem> MyCart
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["cart"] == null)
                {
                    ViewState["cart"] = new List<CartItem>();
                }

                return ViewState["cart"] as List<CartItem>;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                BindProdGrid();
        }

        protected void BindProdGrid()
        {
            gvProd.DataSource = GetProducts();
            gvProd.DataBind();
        }

        protected List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            var ret = new List<Product>();

            ret.Add(new Product(1));
            ret.Add(new Product(2));

            return ret;
        }

        protected void gvProd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
            {
                var row = (e.CommandSource as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
                var ddl = row.FindControl("ddlQty") as DropDownList;

                var qty = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.SelectedValue);
                var pid = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                AddToCart(pid, qty, increase: true);
                BindCartGrid(this.MyCart);
            }
        }

        protected void AddToCart(int pid, int qty, bool increase = false)
        {
            var cartItem = this.MyCart.Find(o => o.Prod.PID == pid);
            if (cartItem == null)
                this.MyCart.Add(new CartItem(new Product(pid), qty));
            else
                if (increase)
                    cartItem.Qty += qty;
                else
                    cartItem.Qty = qty;
        }

        protected void gvProd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                var item = e.Row.DataItem as Product;

                var litNm = e.Row.FindControl("litNm") as Literal;
                litNm.Text = item.Name;

                var ddlQty = e.Row.FindControl("ddlQty") as DropDownList;
                ddlQty.Items.Add(new ListItem("1", "1"));
                ddlQty.Items.Add(new ListItem("10", "10"));

                var lbnAdd = e.Row.FindControl("lbnAdd") as LinkButton;
                lbnAdd.CommandArgument = item.PID.ToString();
            }
        }

        protected void BindCartGrid(List<CartItem> items)
        {
            gvCart.DataSource = items;
            gvCart.DataBind();
        }

        protected void gvCart_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                var item = e.Row.DataItem as CartItem;

                var litNm = e.Row.FindControl("litNm") as Literal;
                litNm.Text = item.Prod.Name + " (pid:" + item.Prod.PID.ToString() + ")";

                var txtQty = e.Row.FindControl("txtQty") as TextBox;
                txtQty.Text = item.Qty.ToString();
                txtQty.Attributes["data-pid"] = item.Prod.PID.ToString();
            }
        }

        protected void gvCart_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "UpdateCart")
            {
                var row = (e.CommandSource as Button).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
                var txtQty = row.FindControl("txtQty") as TextBox;

                var qty = Convert.ToInt32(txtQty.Text);
                var pid = Convert.ToInt32(txtQty.Attributes["data-pid"]);

                AddToCart(pid, qty, increase: false);
                BindCartGrid(this.MyCart);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usage of Cache object vs Session again will depend upon whether you want the data to be stored  temporarily per session or for all the sessions you want to store the same data.
Session can be used if you want the same data to be maintained only for a particular session of your application. 
Cache can be used for all the user sessions across your application.

Answer (score 0):

To address data persistence between postbacks you have several options. I am really against ViewState except in very specific cases where you have a very little amount of data (that's where Microsoft fail in WebForms - its default behaviour is DemoWare).

I would suggest keeping your data in a [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) object and upon postback, read it from that object. But it really depends on your specific use case. There are different techniques.

Comment: I mean when the page is Posted Back

Answer (score 0):

The best place to store the data will be sessions. Viewstate will bring all the data on client side which is an undesirable network/bandwidth overhead.

your PageStart should look like this:

```
public void PageStart()
{
if(Session["dt"] == null || !(Session["dt"] is datatable)){


datatable dt;
///your dt populating code
Session["dt"] = dt;
}
yourGridView.datasource = (datatable)Session["dt"];
yourGridView.databind();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is all what you need to do.
>   Place you method or function which fills the gridview with data like this.

```
private void FillGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = //Fill you datatable
    Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
    Gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

> This is what you gotta do on pageload event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    if (!IsPostBack)  
    {  
        this.FillGrid();  
    }  
}
```